# how to put arrow shape inside cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm working on a macro to generate comparison between numbers and i have the specific task to add some shapes near the text of every cell.

I tried to figure out how to calculate x, y, width, height in order to nicely place them in the cell, but without success.
I asked about that in a previous question and also obtaines a nice answer, but since i have a specific request i need the vba way to do this.

Any suggestions?

```
Dim s As Shape, sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveSheet
If arrType = "Up" Then
    Set s = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeUpArrow, x, y, width, height)
  Else
    Set s = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDownArrow, x, y, width, height)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next adapted code, please. It happens I know your previous question on this theme, too:

```
Sub Compare_numbers()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim arrA, txt As String
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = sh.cells(rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If sh.cells(i, "L").Value = sh.cells(i, "M").Value Then
            sh.cells(i, "N").Value = "they are equal"
            arrA = isArrow(sh.Range("N" & i), "")
        ElseIf sh.cells(i, "L").Value > sh.cells(i, "M").Value Then
            With sh.cells(i, "N")
                .Value = "L is greater than M    ."
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
            arrA = isArrow(sh.Range("N" & i), "Up")
            If arrA(0) = "OK" Then
                If arrA(1) <> "Up" Then
                    insertArrow sh.Range("N" & i), "Up"
                End If
            Else
                insertArrow sh.Range("N" & i), "Up"
            End If
        Else
            With sh.cells(i, "N")
                .Value = "L is greater than M    ." 'Used this solution to Autofit on the larger text...
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
                .Value = "L is less than M          ."
            End With
            arrA = isArrow(sh.Range("N" & i), "Down")
            If arrA(0) = "OK" Then
                If arrA(1) <> "Down" Then
                    insertArrow sh.Range("N" & i), "Down"
                End If
            Else
                insertArrow sh.Range("N" & i), "Down"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It needs the following `Sub` inserting the appropriate arrow:

```
Sub insertArrow(rng As Range, arrType As String)
  Dim sh As Worksheet, s As Shape
  Dim leftP As Double, topP As Double, W As Double, H As Double
  
  Set sh = rng.Parent
  W = 8: H = 12 'set the arrow width and height (you can change them)
  leftP = rng.left + rng.width - W - 1  'calculate the horiz position
  topP = rng.top + (rng.height - H) / 2 'calculate the vert position

  If arrType = "Up" Then
    Set s = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeUpArrow, leftP, topP, W, H)
  Else
    Set s = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDownArrow, leftP, topP, W, H)
  End If
  s.Name = s.Name & "-" & rng.Address 'add the cell address to be able
                                      'to bring back the arrows moved by mistake
  s.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse: s.placement = xlMoveAndSize
End Sub
```

And the next `Function` able to check if a shape is an arrow and what type:

```
Function isArrow(rng As Range, typeArr As String) As Variant
  Dim s As Shape, sh As Worksheet, arr
  
  Set sh = rng.Parent 'extract the range sheet where it belongs
  For Each s In sh.Shapes
    If s.TopLeftCell.Address = rng.Address Then 'match the range address with the shape TLCell address
        If left(s.Name, 2) = typeArr Or left(s.Name, 4) = typeArr Then
            isArrow = Array("OK", typeArr): Exit Function
        Else
            If left(s.Name, 2) = "UP" Or left(s.Name, 4) = "Down" Then
                isArrow = Array("OK", IIf(typeArr = "Up", "Down", "Up"))
                s.Delete: Exit Function
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
  Next
  isArrow = Array("No", "")
  'the function creates an array able to 'tell' if the shape is an arrow and its type
End Function
```

Unfortunately, there is no event able to be triggered by the cell sizes change. But, try the next event, which act when you double click a cell. Please, copy it in the sheet code module, where you need to insert arrows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim lastR As Long, s As Shape, i As Long, addr As String
    
    'bring back the arrows moved by mistakes:
    For Each s In Me.Shapes
        If left(s.Name, 2) = "Up" Or left(s.Name, 4) = "Down" Then
            addr = Split(s.Name, "-")(UBound(Split(s.Name, "-")))
            If addr <> s.TopLeftCell.Address Then
                s.left = Me.Range(addr).left + 10
                s.top = Me.Range(addr).top + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'last row on the column to be processed (N:N):
    lastR = Me.Range("N" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Me.Range("L:N").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter 'to look nicer
    For i = 2 To lastR
        arrangeSh Me.Range("N" & i)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub arrangeSh(rng As Range)
  Dim sh As Shape
  
  For Each sh In rng.Parent.Shapes
    If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = rng.Address Then
        'bring back the row height if is less then the arrow height:
        If rng.height < 12 Then rng.EntireRow.height = 12
        sh.width = 8: sh.height = 12 'reset the arrow dimensions
        'reposition the arrows:
        sh.top = rng.top + (rng.height - sh.height) / 2
        sh.left = rng.left + rng.width - sh.width - 1
        Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

It will firstly check if the arrow has been moved by mistake and bring it back on the 'mother' cell, then place it centered, at 1 point from the right cell side.

The event code can be placed in a sub, let us say `reArrangeShapes`, the event will have a single line `reArrangeShapes`, and this sub may be called from different sheet events (Calculate, Activate, Deactivate etc.). Doing its job when the events in discussion are triggered.

The subs can be optimized using `Appliction.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning followed by `Appliction.ScreenUpdating = True` and and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

If something unclear, please, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

**Edited**:

In order to better understand what's happening the `isArrow` function can be tested using the next sub. You should select a cell (having or not an arrow and run the code:

```
Sub testIsArrow()
  Debug.Print isArrow(ActiveCell, "Up")(0)
End Sub
```

What does it return in `Immediate Window` (being in IDE, press `Ctrl + G`)?
You must understand that if the active cell keeps an arrow not being "Up" type, the shape will be deleted...

Comment: thanks a lot for all your efforts, i really appreciate it. Anyway i had an error once i lauched it, on this String: 
'Function isArrow(rng As Range, typeArr As String) As Variant' the debug says: “Compile Error: Expected Array”.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Alex D.: Do you want meaning that the line you copied becomes yellow and the error you mentioned is raised? Do you name like 'String' the code line defining the function? It shouldn't raise such an error since the function parameters are `Range` and `String`. Can you better explain what's happening? Then, if not something confidential, can you share the workbook (or a dummy one) you try processing?

Comment: @Alex D.:  I edited the above answer and post a small function able to test the 'problematic' function (in your case). I also adapted a little the function to not delete other shapes then arrows. Theoretically it was not necessary, if the code runs on the appropriate range, but just in case. So, it would be good to copy the updated function.

Comment: i fixed the error, now it works perfectly. Appreciated the help

Comment: @Alex D.: May I know what was necessary to be fixed?

Comment: of course, i had already a code inside the Sheet code module, i just removed that code and left only yours, it worked!